# How to add dynamic class for formly-field based on controller property?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-formly

I need to add conditional Class to Form Field based on control property.

for Ex : i have in my controller

```
 $scope.isIssueFixed = true;
```

and my formly object is -

```
$scope.formly = {
className: 'col-xs-6',
key: 'Name',
type: 'input',
templateOptions: {
label: 'Common Device Name'
}
```

Now how we can add a condition class to above formly field,
$scope.isIssueFixed?'ok':'No'; in formly object?

Answer (score 2):

I solved the issue using Wrappers in angular formly. Here is the code which I did. May be it helps to someone.

add the bolow code to config :

```
formlyConfigProvider.setWrapper({
      name: 'horizontalBootstrapLabel',
      template: [
        `<label for="{{::id}}" class="col-sm-2 control-label" >
          '{{to.label}} {{to.required ? "*" : ""}}
        </label>
        <div class="col-sm-8" ng-class="{'bbb':model.heightlight}">
          <formly-transclude></formly-transclude>
        </div>`
      ].join(' ')
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $scope.$watch('isIssueFixed', function() {
        var classAdded = $scope.isIssueFixed ? "ok" , "No";  $scope.formly = {
                 className: 'col-xs-6 ' + classAdded  ,
                 key: 'products.device[0].deviceCommonName',
                 type: 'input',
                 templateOptions: {
                 label: 'Common Device Name'
                }
    });
```

Comment: the above solution is not working, I need dynamically adding class based on condition , in above solution class will not update if the control property changed. Thanks for answering. Whenever scope.IsIssuefixed changes i wnat to update the class in formly field

Comment: Updated the answer try it now 1

Answer (score -1):

You can use ng-class directive of angularjs. Refere https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass.

Comment: Hey kaushlendras, Thanks for your quick response , but i want to change the class dynamically in template Options using ExpressionProperties?